# How to convert list of Series to a two columns dataframe?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, series

I have the following list of Series.

```
[LVH = 0    63 (88.73 %)
 LVH = 1      6 (8.45 %)
 LVH = 2      1 (1.41 %)
 LVH = 3      1 (1.41 %)
 dtype: object, LV diastolic dysfunction (guideline) = 0    60 (84.51 %)
 LV diastolic dysfunction (guideline) = 1     8 (11.27 %)
 LV diastolic dysfunction (guideline) = 4      3 (4.23 %)
 dtype: object, LV diastolic dysfunction grade (formula) = 0.0    60 (84.51 %)
 LV diastolic dysfunction grade (formula) = 1.0      4 (5.63 %)
 LV diastolic dysfunction grade (formula) = 3.0      4 (5.63 %)
 LV diastolic dysfunction grade (formula) = 4.0      3 (4.23 %)
 dtype: object, LV filling pressure(formula) = 0    67 (94.37 %)
 LV filling pressure(formula) = 1      4 (5.63 %)
 dtype: object, cause of hospitalization = 8      2 (2.82 %)
 cause of hospitalization = 1    43 (60.56 %)
 cause of hospitalization = 2    21 (29.58 %)
 cause of hospitalization = 3      1 (1.41 %)
 cause of hospitalization = 6      4 (5.63 %)
 dtype: object, simplfied cause of hospitalization = 1    43 (60.56 %)
 simplfied cause of hospitalization = 2    22 (30.99 %)
 simplfied cause of hospitalization = 3      4 (5.63 %)
 simplfied cause of hospitalization = 5      2 (2.82 %)
 dtype: object, ACC/AHA = A    10 (14.08 %)
 ACC/AHA = 0    56 (78.87 %)
 ACC/AHA = C      2 (2.82 %)
 ACC/AHA = B      3 (4.23 %)
 dtype: object, ACC-AHA -binary = 0    69 (97.18 %)
 ACC-AHA -binary = 1      2 (2.82 %)
 dtype: object, NYHA = I      65 (91.55 %)
 NYHA = II       2 (2.82 %)
 NYHA = III      4 (5.63 %)
 dtype: object, NYHA-binary = 0    66 (92.96 %)
 NYHA-binary = 1      5 (7.04 %)
 dtype: object]
```

For each element of list, i.e. the Series, I need to convert them to a dataframe with two columns. For example, it should look like the following:

```
Column 1                                      Column 2
LVH = 0                                       63 (88.73 %)
LVH = 1                                        6 (8.45 %)
LVH = 2                                        1 (1.41 %)    
LVH = 3                                        1 (1.41 %)
LV diastolic dysfunction (guideline) = 0      60 (84.51 %)
LV diastolic dysfunction (guideline) = 1       8 (84.51 %)
LV diastolic dysfunction (guideline) = 4       3 (84.51 %)
...
```

And so on. This will then be converted CSV format for people to download. I just used the basic `pd.DataFrame` and also `pd.DataFrame.from_items`. The first one converts it to dataframe but not the way I wanted. The second one gives errors, but I don't think that'll be helpful anyway. How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

```
categorical_vars_multi_class = ['LVH','LV diastolic dysfunction (guideline)','LV diastolic dysfunction grade (formula)','LV filling pressure(formula)','cause of hospitalization','simplfied cause of hospitalization','ACC/AHA','ACC-AHA -binary','NYHA','NYHA-binary']

def getMultiClassData(index,table, prop):
    tab = pd.Series()
    for i in range(len(table)): 
        tab_str = str(table[i]) + " (" + str(prop[i]) + " %)"
        tab = tab.set_value(i,tab_str)
    tab.index = index
    return(tab)


def getMultiClassTable(data,name):
    table = pd.value_counts(data[name].values, sort=False)
    table.index = [name + ' = ' + str(x) for x in table.index]
    prop = (table/table.sum() * 100).round(2)

    return(getMultiClassData(table.index,table.values, prop))



m_cluster_1 = [getMultiClassTable(data,x) for x in categorical_vars_multi_class]
```

`data` is a dataframe with column names and measurements for the variable. The dataset is huge and sensitive.

Comment: give the code in question to generate the list of series

Comment: @meW, I added the code.

Comment: define `data` too

Comment: @meW, Can you elaborate? The `data` is just a dataframe with 287 columns and 128000 rows. The data is also sensitive to provide. I am only interested in the categorical data for looking at its distribution. There are several other datasets with the similar data. I'll run the code for each dataframe and put in the dataframe and (eventually excel spreadsheet) for users to see how different (or similar) they are for each dataset group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't replicate your example due to unknown `data`, so I formed my own sample example. You can get help from this -

```
s1 = pd.Series(['1kg', '2kg'], index=['first', 'second'])
s2 = pd.Series(['3kg', '4kg'], index=['third', 'fourth'])
lst = [s1, s2]
lst

# [first     1kg
#  second    2kg
#  dtype: object, third     3kg
#  fourth    4kg
#  dtype: object]

ndf = pd.concat(lst,  axis = 1, keys=[s.name for s in lst], sort=False).fillna('').apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
ndf = pd.DataFrame(ndf).reset_index()
ndf.columns = ['Column 1', 'Column 2']
ndf


+---+----------+----------+
|   | Column 1 | Column 2 |
+---+----------+----------+
| 0 | first    | 1kg      |
| 1 | second   | 2kg      |
| 2 | third    | 3kg      |
| 3 | fourth   | 4kg      |
+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!!!! Thank you so much!!! I only had to remove `sort=False` since I got an erorr stating `pd.concat has no sort function`. I removed it, it worked. I'll work on the sorting to find out why it's not working.